# bash unzip partial directory structure from zip file

Tags: bash, zip

Clients submit large (1.5gigs, >10,000 files) zip files with their directory structure from clients' OUTPUT directory. I want to bash unzip to my INPUT directory, preserving their directory structure also, BUT NOT the ENTIRE directory structure.

For example, if their zip file contains the files:

```
/home/base/data/output/able/file1.xml
/home/base/data/output/able/file2.xml
/home/base/data/output/able/file3.xml
/home/base/data/output/baker/file1.xml
/home/base/data/output/baker/file2.xml
/home/base/data/output/baker/file3.xml
/home/base/data/output/charlie/file1.xml
/home/base/data/output/charlie/file2.xml
/home/base/data/output/charlie/file3.xml
```

(this goes on for thousands of files in about a dozen unique directories)

I want to unzip them to my INPUT directory as below:

```
../input/able/file1.xml
../input/able/file2.xml
../input/able/file3.xml
../input/baker/file1.xml
../input/baker/file2.xml
../input/baker/file3.xml
../input/charlie/file1.xml
../input/charlie/file2.xml
../input/charlie/file3.xml
```

So far I tried:

```
unzip BIGFILE.zip   /output/   input
```

--(*) before and after /output/

which does unzip all xml files with the directory structure of `able/baker/charlie`, etc. HOWEVER, it also unpacks the entire file structure BEFORE /output:

```
../input/home/base/data/output/able/file1.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/able/file2.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/able/file3.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/baker/file1.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/baker/file2.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/baker/file3.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/charlie/file1.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/charlie/file2.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/charile/file3.xml
```

Probably can't be done in a one liner, but I haven't found any scripts
that would read in the partial directory a couple thousand files, then 
unzip them to a specific directory.
Any thoughts?

Comment: why not first extract to `path/input/tmp` directory then just `mv path/input/tmp/home/base/data/output/* path/input` ?

Comment: I fixed the formatting in your question (you might want to have a look at [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to see how to do this). But I am not sure what you meant by `--(*) before and after /output/`. Could you please [edit] and clarify that? If you tried two commands, show us both commands.

Comment: Thanx so much for  your quick response.  --(*) means BEFORE the string "/output"/ and AFTER the string "/output/" is an *.  That's all.  When I use the *  in this web page as I do in the actual command it is interpreted as some kind of formatting and is not visible.  Works in the command, though.  And thanx for the formatting assistance.

Comment: There is a beta version of the Infozip unzip program (version 6.1 I think) that can achieve exactly what you want in one step. The `-j` option in the newer unzip version allows you to drop parts of the path before writing to the filesystem. In your case you want to drop the first four parts of the path, namely `/home/base/data/output`,  so if you are already in the `input` directory running `unzip -j=4 home.zip` would do what you need.